# Sort query results by data from another request (ElasticSearch)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the enormous index contained the quite static data:

```
{
  "main" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "students" : {
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "age" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And another indexes contained dynamic data. For example:

```
{
  "dynamic" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "ratings" : {
        "properties" : {
          "student" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "rating" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We need to sort the query to first index by ratings from the second index. Is it really?

Getting the all data from first index and then sorting at my site backend is quite unefficient.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this data should all be contained in a single index. Do students have 1 or more ratings? If so, nest a student's ratings on the student document so you can write more complex queries and sort on nested values.

Remember that elasticsearch is not relational. There's no way to "combine" different indexes like you would combine different tables in SQL. If you want to query information together, it needs to be indexed together.